# What are the quarantine requirements in Northern Ireland for Irish citizens?

Tags: northern-ireland

I'll be travelling to Belfast for a day on the 26th of this month after Christmas. I'm not sure if there are quarantine requirements. I was told that the border free zone would make this a non-issue.

Comment: Will you be traveling from the Republic of Ireland?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing where you’ll be travelling *from*, but this https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/coronavirus-covid-19-travelling-within-common-travel-area might help

Comment: @Traveller I'm travelling from the Republic of Ireland by train (Irish Rail).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.